# Syntax to finding first and last nodes in dataset using GraphAware Timetree in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphaware

I am currently running `neo4j 3.3.5` (browser). The database is populated with data and I have installed both `GraphAware framework` and `GraphAware timetree`.  The database and plugins are working great and I have been able to follow some of the `GraphAware` examples Cypher queries.  However, most of the examples I have reviewed they already know the specific date and time.

The data model can be seen below. The red circle is an action node and the blue circle is an object node.

Data Model

[image: Data Model]

So, my question is, what Cypher query can I run to find both the first and last action node in my dataset? The second node has a time property with a long time as the value (`time:1499348050`). The action node has a timestamp property with a long time as the value (`timestamp:14993480500000`).

Comment: Thanks for helping with the edits Bruno.

Comment: I figured it out!  

The following will give you the MAX timestamp:  

MATCH (sec:Second)<-[time:AT_TIME]-(act:action)-[:TARGET]->(obj:object)
RETURN MAX(act.timestamp)